# mapboxgl.Marker() add to Layer instead Map

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I want to use mapboxgl.Marker() since I need to build a custom < div> and stylize it by css.
But I also need to use:

- map.queryRenderedFeatures() - to get information about visible markers on the screen
- map.setLayoutProperty() - to filter markers like groups

**Question:** Can I use mapboxgl.Marker() to place it on Layer, not on Map?
Or can be another way of use mapboxgl.Marker() with map.queryRenderedFeatures() and map.setLayoutProperty()?

I see a possible hack: combine Layer with invisible layer-markers, and over them set mapboxgl.Marker(). This will allow me to use map.queryRenderedFeatures(), but map.setLayoutProperty(id, 'visibility', 'none') will still not work.